# Send a BOOL value to a Fragment Shader OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS / iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I'm new to OpenGL ES 2.0 so please bear with me... I'd like to pass a BOOL flag into my fragment shader so that after a certain touch event has occurred in my app, it renders gl_FragColor differently. I tried using a vec2 attribute for this and just "faking" the .x value as my "BOOL" but it looks like OpenGL is normalizing the value from 0.0 to 1.0 before the shader gets ahold of it. So even though in my app I've set it to 0.0, while the shader is doing its thing, the value will eventually reach 1.0. Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

**VertexAttrib Code:**

```
// set up context, shaders, use program etc.

[filterProgram addAttribute:@"inputBrushMode"];
inputBrushModeAttribute = [filterProgram attributeIndex:@"inputBrushMode"];

bMode[0] = 0.0;
bMode[1] = 0.0;

glVertexAttribPointer(inputBrushModeAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, bMode);
```

**Current Vertex Shader Code:**

```
...
attribute vec2 inputBrushMode;
varying highp float brushMode;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    ...
    brushMode = inputBrushMode.x;
}
```

**Current Fragment Shader Code:**

```
...
varying highp float brushMode;

void main()
{
    if(brushMode < 0.5) {
        // render the texture
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    } else {
        // cover things in yellow funk
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1,1,0,1);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it looks like OpenGL is normalizing the value from 0.0 to 1.0 before the shader gets ahold of it" First, why aren't you using a uniform? Why use a vertex attribute? Second, where is your setup code for providing this attribute? Are you using `glVertexAttribPointer` correctly?

Comment: I was under the impression that a uniform's value can't be changed later on, is that not true? I'm pretty sure I'm using `glVertexAttribPointer` correctly - I'll add that code. Thanks.

Comment: You can change uniform values at any time (except in the middle of a batch).

Comment: @taber: Uniforms don't change *within* a draw call. But they can be changed between draw calls with `glUniform`. They are "uniform" compared to "attribute" and "varying". The thing that can't be changed ever is `const`.

Comment: Ah nice, thanks, I'll have to give uniforms a shot. Is it possible to pass a single float as a uniform or will it need to also be a vec2 array pointer?

Comment: You can pass single float as `uniform` or as `attribute` (). I'm a bit confused by your code: how many primitives of what kind are you drawing (`GL_POINT`, `GL_TRIANGLE`,...)? You seem to use an array with 3 entries as input for your attribute, this means you can only draw one point. If you want to use an attribute, you have to store two values in your array for each vertex you are rendering.

Comment: Ah okay, using a uniform worked! @kroneml sorry about that, bSize and the extra bMode shouldn't have been in my example code. Thanks Nicol - since you answered first if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create the bool as a `glUniform` (1.0 or 0.0) instead. Set its value with `glUniform1f(GLint location, GLfloat v0)`. In the shader, check its value like so:

```
if (my_uniform < 0.5) {
    // FALSE
} else {
    // TRUE
}
```

Comment: Because of float precision.

Comment: If you set it to be 0.0 or 1.0 manually, you shouldn't encounter the precision issue. If you're doing mathematical operations on the float before you pass it in, that's when you're at risk of a round-off error.

Comment: @taber nice one, been looking for a solution for this for months.